# Subset data frame based on variable whose type is factor

Tags: r

I have a data frame carList . It has a variable State which is of type factor ,example :

```
Price Year Mileage City  State  Make  Model  
8600 2016   14872  Miami  FL    Honda Civic
```

I want to subset carList whose state is "CA"

```
> nlevels(carList$State)
[1] 59 

subsetForCA <- subset(carList,carList$State=="CA")
```

But I get No results .How can I subset the above data set based on State which is a factor ?

Comment: Can you chexk if there are any leading/lagging spaces i.e. try `subset(carList, trimws(State) == "CA")`

Comment: Your code should work and return results provided there are rows where `State = "CA"`. Note: you don't need `carList$State` in `subset()` - just `State` will work.

Comment: @akrun Ok Seem it was due to trimws , subsetForCivicCA <- subset(subsetForCivic,trimws(State)=="CA") ,did solve the issue .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue could be due to leading/lagging spaces.  If that is the case, `trimws` could remove if there any of those spaces, and then do a `==` on that trimmed column

```
subset(carList, trimws(State) == "CA")
```

---

This can also be done with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
carList %>%
     filter(str_trim(State) == "CA")
```